# Ubuntu will not shutdown

Tags: 11.04, wubi, shutdown

I have installed Ubuntu as wubi (next to windows 7). When I expect the computer to shut down, it doesn't, it freezes instead.

I've found this elsewhere:

```
sudo modprobe -rf rt2860sta; sudo modprobe rt2860sta; echo blacklist rt2800pci | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Is there some way for me to figure out, whether this is right for me?  This fixes "wrong driver loaded", but how can I check which driver I have, and whether it is wrong?

Comment: Please provide us with a little more information as to which version you are using.

Comment: is there anything interesting in your logs?

Comment: System: Ubuntu 11.04.

Not sure which logs to look in.

Comment: Laptop, HP 620.

Comment: I've found this elsewhere:

sudo modprobe -rf rt2860sta;
sudo modprobe rt2860sta;
echo blacklist rt2800pci | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

-- Is there some way for me to figure out, whether this is right for me?

Comment: Like, this fixes "wrong driver loaded". How can I check which driver I have, and whether that it wrong? OR are these commands harmless?

Comment: Okay, tried it, doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, current state of affairs:

```
lisea@ubuntu:~$ bin/rtcheck.sh 
-----------------------------------------------
SUSPEND_MODULES="rt2800pci"
-----------------------------------------------
blacklist rt2800pci
-----------------------------------------------
parport_pc             32111  0 
rt2860sta             494649  1 
crc_ccitt              12595  1 rt2860sta
parport                36746  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
-----------------------------------------------
lisea@ubuntu:~$ 
lisea@ubuntu:~$ cat bin/rtcheck.sh 
#/bin/sh

echo "-----------------------------------------------"
cat /etc/pm/config.d/config 
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
tail -n 1 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
lsmod | grep rt
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
```

In part this was achieved through these commands:

```
sudo modprobe -rf rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -rf rt2860sta
sudo modprobe rt2860sta
```

I blacklisted rt2800pci first (meaning it won't be loaded in the future), then removed it right now with the 3 commands above. The computer froze as a result of the last command, but after boot it finally did what it was supposed to do.

**Success! My computer finally understands how a shutdown works!**

Comment: Would you check your own answer as accepted one if that's what worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to run from the terminal window:

```
sudo halt
```

or

```
sudo init 0
```

Comment: sudo halt leads to freeze.

Comment: sudo init 0 also leads to freeze.

Comment: Could you please describe how exactly it freezes ? I doesn't respond to anything ? Does the display go black ? What does it do ?

Comment: It doesn't respond to anything. My impression is, that it goes through house keeping (e.g. panel disappears), and at some random time during this freezes. Sometimes a picture will be left, sometimes the screen will be black. And then it does nothing, until I press and hold the power button, and it powers down that way.

Comment: Are you running any other operating system along-side Ubuntu ?

Also, here are a few more commands for you to try but I doubt it'll do anything.

`sudo shutdown -h now`

Or

`sudo poweroff`

Comment: I have Windows 7, and Ubuntu as wubi, that's it.

Comment: sudo shutdown -h now leads to freeze.

Comment: Well then, in that case you could always try to boot of a live cd in the system as root and try to repair the packages, but I'm not too sure on how you coukd do that... If that is not an option, I would do a clean install.

Comment: Not too long ago I did a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

I could not follow this advice.  My system did not have the same files.
I finally just reloaded with Ubuntu 11.10 32bit rather than 64 bit.  seems to be working.